# How to allow underscore in self-defined command?

Tags: macros, syntax, underscore

For example, those lines works perfectly fine.

```
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{9709_s10_qp_11_Q3} \\
\flushright \verb=9709_s10_qp_11_Q3= \\[2ex]
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{9709_s10_qp_12_Q7} \\
\flushright \verb=9709_s10_qp_11_Q3= \\[2ex]
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{9709_s10_qp_13_Q1} \\
\flushright \verb=9709_s10_qp_11_Q3= \\[2ex]
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{9709_s11_qp_11_Q8} \\
```

To save time, I want to define a new command `mytopic` (to use in `enumerate`),

```
\newcommand{\mytopic}[1]{%
\item { \flushright \verb= {#1} = } \\
    \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{#1} \\[2ex]
}%
```

The problem arises as I have lots of underscore in my filenames, which I don't really want o rename.

How can I adapt it so that it take the `filename` as well as enabling the `verb` output on the filename? I tried to use `\texttt{}` but it seems to have the same problem.

Comment: For one thing, the issue is not only the underscore, but you cannot place `\verb` inside a macro definition.

Comment: Replace `\verb= {#1} =` with `\detokenize{ {#1} }`.  I believe that is the issue, not the underscore.  i.e., try this definition: `\newcommand{\mytopic}[1]{\item  \flushright \detokenize{ {#1} } \\
    \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{#1} \\[2ex]
}`

Comment: unrelated but `\flushright` is doing nothing in `{ \flushright \verb= {#1} = }` as the scope ends at the `}` before it can affect the paragraph setting.

Comment: You want to handle underscores in *command arguments* (in commands you write yourself), and ship them off to other commands.

Answer (score 3):

The command `\path` from `hyperref` is handy here:

```
\newcommand{\mytopic}[1]{%
\item {\path{#1}} \\
    \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{#1} \\[2ex]
  }

\begin{enumerate}
   \mytopic{DSC_0942}
 \end{enumerate}
```

`\path` allows underscores and other characters used for file paths -- exactly what you need.

Comment: Is `\path` a recent addition to [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? I can't find this command in the documentation or in the source code?

Comment: @Andrew It's defined in `url.sty` that's loaded by `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg I am so used to always loading hyperref, that I forget where the goodies are :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! `\path` very useful indeed！